# Type inference in C++ with an abstract base type

Tags: c++, types, type-inference

Let's say we have classes A and B that are derived from the abstract class X. I have a variable c in which if it is 0 use an instance of A, 1 use an instance of B. Is it possible to write a function or an `if` statement that checks the value of c and returns an instance of the corresponding type?

Comment: `c == 0 ? new A : new B;` Or similar.

Comment: Then what? void pointer?

Comment: A and B derive from X, right? Where does the void pointer come in?

Comment: Yes but X is abstract class

Comment: You can have pointers to an abstract class. `X* x = new B;`

Comment: Well, first time I hear of that. I'll try it and give you feedback ASAP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as long as the pointer is cast into a base class pointer. For example the following works.

```
X* create_instance(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    case 0:
        return new A;
    case 1:
        return new B;
    default:
        return nullptr; // Or throw for invalid type, or do nothing becaues type is assumed to be valid
    }
}
```

Which is simply used as

```
int c = ...;
X* p = create_instance(c);
```

But basically any expression that returns a pointer to `A` or `B` whose value is stored in a `X*` works. That's why DeiDei's comment (`c == 0 ? new A : new B;`) does the same thing concisely.

That said, owning raw pointers are dangerous. You should in most cases return a `unique_ptr` unless that object's lifetime is managed elsewhere and you just want a non-owning pointer.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is save the derived class as a pointer to it's base type. This way it can act as it's base class and in simple `if else` statement you can do what you want to achieve in your question.

here is full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class X {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class A: public X {
    public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

class B: public X {
    public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

int main() {
    bool what = true;
    std::unique_ptr<X> a;
    if (what) {
        a = std::make_unique<A>();
    } else {
        a = std::make_unique<B>();
    }
    a->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: Please don't use `new` and raw pointers if not necessary.

Comment: Why not using new as you mentioned?

Comment: Every time you allocate some memory with `new` keyword you have to dealocate it by calling `delete` manually and when using raw pointers you can move them to some other address and then have a hanging lost memory with almost no access to leaked. By using smart pointers, such as `unique_ptr`, most of these problems are solved, without you needing to think about memory management all the time.

Comment: What if we have methods in A and B that are not in X?

Comment: Then you must first cast the base pointer to the derived pointer but unlike the other way around, this wont work every time, because you can't be sure which type it actually is.